# Polymorphism for geometric forms

Tags: polymorphism

I am developing a small drawing application, with a little library of "complex" forms to be dragged and dropped.

I'm always in doubt when I'm growing a large hierarchy of objects extending from a bunch of others. Especially, I don't always know what is best practice, to extend objects for pure code compression purposes, or to extend objects only when it semantically makes sense to do so.

Here I have a simple example. I have a square object with one property : edge. And then a rectangle and many other shapes. Should rectangle extend from square as it just adds a parameter ? Or should I do the reverse as square is a specialization of rectangle in maths ? Both ways seem to present issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that extending implies an **is a** relation.  In your case, making rectangle extend square is like saying "A rectangle **is a** square" (which it's not, necessarily, in terms of geometry).  For this reason, it makes more sense to me to make square extend rectangle, since "A square **is a** rectangle" is more correct.

In general, it seems like having the "edge" property in square or rectangle is weird, if you plan to include "many other shapes".  I would suggest a **Polygon** class, which contains a set of edges, then a **Rectangle** or **Quadrilateral** class that extends Polygon, then perhaps a **Square** or **[Regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) Quadrilateral** class which extends that.

Comment: but I'm annoyed by the fact that rectangle has two properties. We could argue to chose one to arbitrarily be reused in the square as "edge", but what about the second property of rectangle that is certainly visible, but is not relevant to square ?

Comment: What is the other property besides `edge`?  Also note that I've updated my answer to include a sample of how your hierarchy could go.

Comment: It could be argued that a square doesn't even exist. The shape is always a rectangle, but sometimes all the edges are close to equal.

Comment: "edge" is the only property for square, there's just an extra one inherited from an abstract "absctractObject" which is the "Position"

Comment: It seems like what you're saying is that it's *inconvenient* no matter which way you do it, due to the extra property.  But I would consider it to be *incorrect* (in terms of design) for you to make rectangle extend square.  I also agree with @drharris here; a square is just a rectangle whose sides happen to be equal.  If it's not benefiting you to make the distinction, then don't.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan's answer is the most correct, but consider just making everything a simple `Shape : Polygon` relationship. What is there to gain from deriving Square from Rectangle (if indeed you even need a Square at all)? If there's nothing to gain, then don't do it. That should be the #1 principle of OOP. Huge class hierarchies are difficult to maintain, so your first step is to determine if you even need to do that.

Also, you seem to have confusion about what inheritance means. Inheritance is not simply the quality of having more parameters or methods than the parent class, it is rather the quality of being *a subset* of that class per the domain rules. Most times there will be additional properties, but not always. Like Jonathan said, a rectangle *is not* a square in real life, therefore it cannot derive from the `Square` class.

In your example of rectangle and square, you seem adamant that `Square` only has a single parameter, `edge`, but what's keeping it from having both `width` and `length` parameters, each being equal? In such a case, you can claim *a square is a rectangle that enforces the rule of equal length and width*. It's simple that way, and doesn't violate OO.

Answer (score 0):

Treating inheritance as an "is as" relationship breaks down under even very simple examples like this.

### Square is a Rectangle?

As you have pointed out in your question, a square seems like a special type of rectangle.  This fact suggests that rectangle should inherit from square.  However, consider this code:-

```
foo( Rectangle r )
{
  r.setWidth( 5 );
  r.setHeight( 10 );
  print( r.getWidth() );
}
```

Depending on if you pass in an instance of `Rectangle` or `Square`, the answer would be different.  `Square` can not be substituted for `Rectangle`.  In some sense, square isn't a rectangle.  Adding constraints to a child class breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Inheritance is not a good fit when the child class has extra constraints not present in the parent class.

### Rectangle is a Square?

So maybe `Rectangle` extends `Square`?  It's like a square with an extra special feature that  `myWidth` can be different from the `myHeight`?

What becomes of the inherited member variable `myEdgeLength`?  It is redundant and any use of it is likely a bug.

A programmer comes along and adds a `getPerimeter()` method to `Square`. This is therefore inherited by `Rectangle`.  It would give the wrong answer.  Inheritance is not helping.

### Delegate

I would suggest that inheritance is no help here at all.  `Square` should instead use a rectangle internally.  On construction of `Square`, it creates it's own internal representation of `Rectangle` and puts this in a member variable.

When, `setEdgeLength` is called, it calls `myRectangle.setWidth( x )` and `myRectangle.setHeigth( x )`.   When getArea() is called, it delegates to `myRectangle.getArea`.

Many other functions could be delegated as well.  Such as: containsPoint, getPerimiter, overlaps, etc.

It's a shame that languages require boilerplate for delegation.